# Llenar Mapview con marcadores desde Json con Retrofit (Ayuda)

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, retrofit

estoy trabajando en una app que llene un MapView con marcadores traidos de un Web Service usando Retrofit, y he estado intentando crear un metodo para añadir todos los marcadores desde Json al MapView, pero solo me añade 1, ¿Alguien sabe en que podria estar fallando o que estoy omitiendo?
Cabe Resaltar que cuando pruebo que me los muestre por consola lo hace sin problemas.

Este es el link del Json:
https://t-organizagroup.com/ws_easyhotel/public/api/ubicacion

**Metodo para Marcadores:**

```
private void cargarMarcadores() {
        markerService = retrofit.create (CoordenadaService.class);
        Call<CoordenadaRespuesta> call = markerService.obtenerMarcadores ();
        call.enqueue (new Callback<CoordenadaRespuesta> () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<CoordenadaRespuesta> call, @NonNull Response<CoordenadaRespuesta> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful ()) {
                    try {
                        CoordenadaRespuesta coordenadaRespuesta = response.body ();
                        listaMarker = Objects.requireNonNull (coordenadaRespuesta).getData ();

                    for (int i = 0; i<listaMarker.size (); i++){
                        Coordenada I = listaMarker.get (i);
//                        Log.i (TAG," Local Latitud: " + I.getLatitud ());
//                        Log.i(TAG, " Local Longitud: " + I.getLongitud ());
                        Double lat = Double.parseDouble (I.getLatitud ());
                        Double lng = Double.parseDouble (I.getLongitud ());
                        String title = I.getNombreEmpresa ();
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                        markerOptions.position (latLng);
                        markerOptions.title (title);
                        markerOptions.icon (BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource (R.drawable.mini_logo_marker));
                        Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker (markerOptions);
                    }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d (TAG_ERROR, "Hay un error");
                        e.printStackTrace ();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i (TAG,"El metodo try ha fallado: " + response.errorBody ());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CoordenadaRespuesta> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i (TAG,"Hay un error en la respuesta: " + t.getMessage ());
            }
        });
    }
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hice la prueba con información parecida y funciona normal, probaste en hacer zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice algunos cambios y ahora si funciona :

```
private void cargarMarcadores() {
        markerService = retrofit.create (CoordenadaService.class);
        Call<CoordenadaRespuesta> call = markerService.obtenerMarcadores ();
        call.enqueue (new Callback<CoordenadaRespuesta> () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<CoordenadaRespuesta> call, @NonNull Response<CoordenadaRespuesta> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful ()) {
                    try {
                        CoordenadaRespuesta coordenadaRespuesta = response.body ();
                        listaMarker = Objects.requireNonNull (coordenadaRespuesta).getData ();

                        for (int i = 0; i<listaMarker.size (); i++){
                            Coordenada I = listaMarker.get (i);
                            Double lat = Double.parseDouble (I.getLatitud ());
                            Double lng = Double.parseDouble (I.getLongitud ());
                            String title = I.getNombreEmpresa ();
                            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                            markerOptions.position (latLng);
                            markerOptions.title (title);
                            markerOptions.icon (BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource (R.drawable.mini_logo_marker));
                            Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker (markerOptions);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d (TAG_ERROR, "Hay un error");
                        e.printStackTrace ();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i (TAG,"El metodo try ha fallado: " + response.errorBody ());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CoordenadaRespuesta> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i (TAG,"Hay un error en la respuesta: " + t.getMessage ());
            }
        });
    }
```